# how to create multiple draggable scrollbar with dependent values?

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to create some draggable scrollbar with dependent value for each scrollbar contained in textbox. 
please help me to fix the problem on textbox, that only one textbox use for all scrollbar in this case .

Html:

```
<div id="sliders">
```

Javascript:

```
for (var i=1; i <= 12; i++) {
var html = '<div>Number '+i
        +'<input type="textbox" disabled="" id="val">'+'</div>'
          +'<div class="slider" id="slider-'+i+'"></div>';

$('#sliders').append(html);
$('#slider-'+i).slider({
    value:50,
    min: 5,
    max:100,
    step: 0,
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    animate: true,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#val').val("" + ui.value + "%");
                                 }
});
```

}
console.log(document.getElementById('sliders').innerHTML);

http://jsfiddle.net/damri/a46GC/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what you want? you have duplicated id attribute  in input text

http://jsfiddle.net/a46GC/2/

```
var i = 1;
for (; i <= 12; i++) {
var html = '<div>Number '+i
        +'<input type="textbox" disabled="" id="val-' + i + '">'+'</div>'
          +'<div class="slider" data-id = "'+i+'" id="slider-'+i+'"></div>';

$('#sliders').append(html);
$('#slider-'+i).slider({
    value:50,
    min: 5,
    max:100,
    step: 0,
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    animate: true,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $('#val-' + id).val(ui.value + "%");
                                 }
});
```

}